# Need the last item updated on a text datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need the last row updated on the text column 'Notes' from dbo.notes. Since I am joining several tables for this report, I included a subquery at the end to extract only the top 1 item for column notes.comments by ordering the selection by the date it is entered. But I keep getting error saying that I cant use = operator for subquery to get text datatype(comments). Please help with a better solution.

Here is my query

```
SELECT
JobsReport.AppointmentNumber,     
JobsReport.MarketDescription,
Hc.Manager_4_ID AS RegionalDirectorID,
Hc.Manager_4_Name AS RegionalDirector,
Hc.Primary_Manager_ID AS SecurityManagerID,
Hc.Primary_Manager_Name AS SecurityManagerName,
Dim.OSV_Supervisor_Employee_Number AS SupervisorID,
Dim.OSV_Supervisor_Full_Name AS Supervisor,
JobsReport.Technician, 
JobsReport.TechnicianId, 
JobsReport.RescheduleRate, 
JobsReport.ServiceType, 
JobsReport.PrimaryService, 
JobsReport.AppointmentDuration, 
JobsReport.Status, 
JobsReport.Substatus, 
Notes.Comments,
JobsReport.AppointmentDate,
JobsReport.CustomerFirstName +' '+JobsReport.CustomerLastName AS CustomerName, 
JobsReport.CustomerAddressOne, 
JobsReport.CustomerCity, 
JobsReport.CustomerState, 
JobsReport.CustomerZip
FROM AT_ATT_Data_Integration.dbo.JobsReport
LEFT JOIN AT_ATT_Data_Integration.dbo.Appointments
ON JobsReport.AppointmentNumber = Appointments. AppointmentNumber
LEFT JOIN AT_ATT_Data_Integration.dbo.Notes
ON Appointments.AppointmentId=Notes.AppointmentId
LEFT JOIN AT_BI_DataStore.dbo.ATT_Employees AS Employee
ON JobsReport.TechnicianId=Employee.[Tech ID]
LEFT JOIN AT_BI_DataStore.dbo.Dim_Employees AS Dim
ON Employee.OracleID=Dim.OSV_Employee_Number
LEFT JOIN [AT_BI_DataStore].[dbo].[Hierarchy_Honeycomb] AS Hc
ON Dim.OSV_BR_Location=Hc.R12_Organization_Name
WHERE (convert(date,JobsReport.AppointmentDate) = convert(date,GETDATE()))
AND Notes.Comments = (
    SELECT TOP 1
    FROM AT_ATT_Data_Integration.dbo.Notes
    ORDER BY Notes.Date DESC)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Patrick is correct; your final WHERE clause is not selecting anything. "SELECT TOP 1" needs a column.
2. You cannot use = to compare `TEXT` columns. You would need a `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Notes.Comments)` on both sides of the = sign for that to work.
3. So you want to include the latest note for that appointment along with the rest of the data. To do this, you can put the subquery as part of the `ON` clause for where that table is joined. Thus, your full query becomes:

```
    SELECT
    JobsReport.AppointmentNumber,     
    JobsReport.MarketDescription,
    Hc.Manager_4_ID AS RegionalDirectorID,
    Hc.Manager_4_Name AS RegionalDirector,
    Hc.Primary_Manager_ID AS SecurityManagerID,
    Hc.Primary_Manager_Name AS SecurityManagerName,
    Dim.OSV_Supervisor_Employee_Number AS SupervisorID,
    Dim.OSV_Supervisor_Full_Name AS Supervisor,
    JobsReport.Technician, 
    JobsReport.TechnicianId, 
    JobsReport.RescheduleRate, 
    JobsReport.ServiceType, 
    JobsReport.PrimaryService, 
    JobsReport.AppointmentDuration, 
    JobsReport.Status, 
    JobsReport.Substatus, 
    JobsReport.AppointmentDate,
    JobsReport.CustomerFirstName +' '+JobsReport.CustomerLastName AS CustomerName, 
    JobsReport.CustomerAddressOne, 
    JobsReport.CustomerCity, 
    JobsReport.CustomerState, 
    JobsReport.CustomerZip
    FROM AT_ATT_Data_Integration.dbo.JobsReport
    LEFT JOIN AT_ATT_Data_Integration.dbo.Appointments
    ON JobsReport.AppointmentNumber = Appointments. AppointmentNumber
    LEFT JOIN AT_ATT_Data_Integration.dbo.Notes
    ON Appointments.AppointmentId=Notes.AppointmentId 
       AND Notes.Date = (
          SELECT TOP 1 Notes.Date 
          FROM AT_ATT_Data_Integration.dbo.Notes AS N2
          WHERE N2.AppointmentId = Notes.AppointmentId
          ORDER BY Notes.Date DESC)
    LEFT JOIN AT_BI_DataStore.dbo.ATT_Employees AS Employee
    ON JobsReport.TechnicianId=Employee.[Tech ID]
    LEFT JOIN AT_BI_DataStore.dbo.Dim_Employees AS Dim
    ON Employee.OracleID=Dim.OSV_Employee_Number
    LEFT JOIN [AT_BI_DataStore].[dbo].[Hierarchy_Honeycomb] AS Hc
    ON Dim.OSV_BR_Location=Hc.R12_Organization_Name
    WHERE (convert(date,JobsReport.AppointmentDate) = convert(date,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a column name in that final sub query. Example, if the column on AT_ATT_Data_Integration.dbo.Notes is called "OldNote":

```
AND Notes.Comments = ( SELECT TOP 1 OldNote FROM AT_ATT_Data_Integration.dbo.Notes ORDER BY Notes.Date DESC)
```

Once you correct that, it should work.

Comment: While this is truly a syntax error in the statement, it does not connect up to the error message he's getting. = operator is not usable with `TEXT` or `NTEXT` datatype.